# Cisco Nexus 5548UP - which side is the 'front'?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

The Cisco Nexus 5548UP switch is sold in a both front-to-back and back-to-front cooling options, but which side is considered the front?

- The side with all the SFP+ ports?
- The side with the management RJ45 ports?

I would want to mount the switch so that the SFP+ ports are at the rear of the rack, in line with the backs of the servers.  Does this mean I should buty the back-to-front model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The front of the switch is the side with the power supplies and the management ports. It would appear that you want front to back airflow based on your orientation and assuming that your hot aisle is in the rear of your rack (which it should be).

Comment: Thanks for this; I found a diagram in the online installation guide  (took me longer than it should have!) and it agrees with you! http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/hw/installation/guide/overview5500.html#wp1258826 shows the 'front view', which is clearly the side with the managment ports and power supplies.

Comment: Glad to help...